# VBScript: Getting error by batch renaming files within a folder

Tags: vbscript, directory, renaming

In this script I try to rename all the files within a folder. The new names I will gather from each textfiles in itself using **Instr(1, strText, "(Amtlicher Gemeindeschlüssel = " ...)**. So all jsp-files  shall be proceed. But I get an object-error almost at the end: **800A01A8 - Object Required**. Can anyone helpme to **replace the object strVerz.files** so the the code works.
*Thank U in advance*.
Michael

```
Dim objFso, strFolder

' Begin Main

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = objFso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)  

If objFso.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
    Call GetJspFiles(objFso.GetFolder(strFolder))
End If

Set objFso = Nothing

' End Main

Sub GetJspFiles(ByRef objFolder)
    Dim objFile, objSubFolder

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "jsp" Then
            Call JSPRename(objFile.Path, objFolder.Path)
        End If
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
      Call GetJspFiles(objSubFolder)
    Next
' objFile.Close

End Sub

Sub JSPRename(ByRef strPath, ByRef strFolder)
    Dim arrText, strText, strTextLine, Position , objJspFile, newFilename, strVerz

    Set objJspFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strPath)

    arrText = Split(objJspFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf) ' split to lines

    For Each strTextLine In arrText
      If strTextLine <> "" Then
         strText = Trim(strTextLine)

       If Instr(1,strText,"(Amtlicher Gemeindeschlüssel",1) Then
        Position=Instr(1, strText, "(Amtlicher Gemeindeschlüssel =",1)
       newFilename=mid(strText,Position+31, 8)

       else
       end if
      end if

    Next

    strVerz=objFSO.GetParentFoldername(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    strNewName = strVerz & "\" & newFilename & ".jsp" 

    ' Wscript.echo strNewName & vbcrlf & strVerz.files '!! only for Showing the results

     objFSO.MoveFile strVerz.files, strNewName <- Here I get the error

     objJspFile.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the purpose of `JSPRename` is to rename the file given by `strPath`.  In that case, the call to [`MoveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6%28VS.84%29.aspx) should look like:

```
objFSO.MoveFile strPath, strNewName
```

Comment: Thanks, but  I get an Error 46 ("Permission denied") at this line

Comment: Thanks, but  I get an Error 46 ("Permission denied") at this line. WScript.Echo gives me **"C:\Test\jhz.jsp\14521670.jsp"**, but it should be **"C:\Test\14521670.jsp"**. How can I kill the "Subdir"-string which is the old filename (**jhz.jsp**) ?

Comment: Hi, after adding some textmanipulating function and moving the **objJspFile.Close** upwards the script works. Here is the end of the Script 
` Next

**objJspFile.Close

    cutlastoff=Left(strPath, inStrRev(strPath,"\")-1)

    strNewName = cutlastoff & "\" & newFilename & ".jsp"**  ' cutting the filename

    ' Wscript.echo "New name: " & strNewName & vbcrlf & "Old Namne: " & strPath '!! only for Showing the results

    objFSO.MoveFile strPath, strNewName
     

End Sub`